# Trying to connect to FTP site but getting wrong SSL version number error?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, ftp

I am using Python 2.7. 
I recently successfully established a connection to my ftp site using port 990. However, there is an un update to the site where I need to switch to port 22. So all I changed was the port number from 990 to 22. However, after I did that I got the error:

```
[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:661)
```

I have tried checking other similar posts which suggest appending https:// to the site. I'm using FTP and not a url so this is not a possibility for me. I have also tried changing the ssl_version to ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 but get the following error:

```
[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:661)
```

Here is my full code provided. Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks for any help.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import socket
import ssl

class tyFTP(FTP_TLS):
    def __init__(self, host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', keyfile=None, certfile=None, context=None, timeout=60):
        FTP_TLS.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, keyfile, certfile, context, timeout)
    def connect(self, host='', port=0, timeout=-999):
        if host != '':
            self.host = host
        if port > 0:
            self.port = port
        if timeout != -999:
            self.timeout = timeout

        try: 
            self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
            self.af = self.sock.family
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
            # self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
            self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
            self.welcome = self.getresp()
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    return self.welcome

FTP_SITE = "sftp.MySite.com"

UPLOAD = {
    "USERNAME": "username",
    "PASSWORD": "password"
}

DOWNLOAD = {
    "USERNAME": "username",
    "PASSWORD": "password"
}

server = tyFTP()
# changed from 990. 990 works with no issues.
server.connect(host=FTP_SITE, port=22)
```

Comment: Is it possible they've reverted to plain old FTP rather than SFTP. Have you tried accessing the server without using SSL?

Comment: They assured me they're migrating to SFTP using SSL.

Comment: SFTP does not use SSL, but SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

990 is the port for implicit FTPS while 22 is the port for SSH and thus also SFTP. My guess is that they did not just switch the port but that they actually switched from FTPS (FTP over SSL) to SFTP (file transfer over SSH). This suggests also the hostname you use: `sftp.MySite.com`.

FTPS and SFTP are completely different protocols and you can not use code implementing FTPS to connect to an SFTP server. For libraries supporting SFTP in Python see [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sftp+python).

Comment: What you said make sense and I'll try that now. Just curious though because I had no issues with the same site `sftp.MySite.com` and code when using port 990. So the code was written for SFTP but still worked on port 990.

Comment: @Alex: FTP_TLS is the library which implements FTP over SSL/TLS, i.e. the FTPS protocol (port 990) and not the SFTP protocol (port 22).